# BIBD or IBD or PBIBD

Tags: experiment-design, combinatorics, conjoint-analysis, blocking, choice-modeling

I use block design for discrete choice experiment. While Balanced incomplete block design(BIBD) is considered as gold standard for blocking in choice experiments. However this is not always possible to generate. BIBD has 2 major properties. It compares

1. each profile appears equal number of times in entire block design exercise and
2. each profile is compared equal number of times with every other profile.

There are similar types of incomplete block designs namely Incomplete Block Design(IBD) and Partially Balanced Incomplete Block Design (PBIBD). While both of these designs may ensure first property of BIBD(each profile appears equal number of times), it can't do the second part. So for second part, either  comparison between some profiles are omitted or every profile is compared with every other profile, however inter-profile comparisons are less in comparison to some other inter-profile comparisons.

For example, we have 4 profiles, each profile is appearing equal times in entire blocking exercise. A and B are compared once, however A and C are compared more than once.

**My question**: How do we decide in such a scenario if resultant IBD or PBIBD block design is 'usable' from statistical efficiency perspective?